# Tag for taking orders and selling prints

Tags: discussion, tags

What would be a good tag to use for doing business/making profit with a 3D printer?

Comment: Before we start creating tags, would such questions even be on-topic here? Such questions would either be too opinion based (how do I price my models), or the monetization aspect would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest two different tags:

- [monetization]: For selling, or profiting from printing, or from printing machines
- [financing] (or [costs]): For calculating the cost of materials and machines, including operational expenses.

Answer (score -2):

I would propose something as [business] or [commercial-use] as opposed to [personal-use] to differentiate between these posibilites.